# Starting a Jenkins Job using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-api

Does anyone have an example of starting a jenkins job with auth and parameterized in Java Script?

Its like a curl post but I am not sure how to do that exactly and I couldn't find any example passing username and token as well as parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`jenkins` npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jenkins) to perform actions on npm using a specific user:

```js
import Jenkins = require('jenkins');

const jenkins

Jenkins({ baseUrl: `https://${ username }:${ password }@${ urlToJenkinsInstance }`, crumbIssuer: true })
      .then((_jenkins) => {
        jenkins = _jenkins;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // start building a job
          jenkins.job.build({
            name: jobName,
            // put all the parameters here:
            parameters: {
              PARAM1: 'hello',
              PARAM2: 'world'
            }
          }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) { return reject(err); }

            resolve(data);
          });
        });
      })
      .then((queueId) => {
        console.log('job queueId: ', queueId);
      })
      .catch(printErrorAndExit);
```

If you need to continue and monitor the flow, after the job is added to the queue, you need to wait for the job to start, which will add a `jobId` to the queue item using `jenkins.queue.item(queueId, callback)`.

Then, you can monitor the actual job and check when it finished.

In the following code, I defined two functions called `convertQueueIdToBuildId` and `waitForJobToFinish`.

#### `convertQueueIdToBuildId`

This will wait for the queue item to get a permanent ID to start and checking for the job status. I defined the interval to check this every 5 seconds.

#### `waitForJobToFinish`

This will get the permanent `jobId` and check every 5 seconds what's the job's status. if it's `SUCCESS`, we can resolve the promise, and if we get either `ABORTED` or `FAILURE`, we error the promise to indicate something didn't go well. We can play with what makes the promise fail or resolve based on the use.

```js
// continuing the previous promise chain:
  .then((queueId) => convertQueueIdToBuildId(jenkins, jobName, queueId, 5000))
  .then((buildId) => waitForJobToFinish(jenkins, jobName, buildId, 5000))
  .catch(printErrorAndExit);

function convertQueueIdToBuildId(jenkins, jobName, queueId, interval, spinner) {
  return convertQueueIdToBuildIdInner(queueId)
    .then((data) => {
      if (isNumber(data)) {
        return data;
      }

      return waitFor(interval)
        .then(() => convertQueueIdToBuildId(jenkins, jobName, queueId, interval, spinner));
    });

  function convertQueueIdToBuildIdInner(queueId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jenkins.queue.item(queueId, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        resolve(data && data.executable && data.executable.number);
      });
    });
  }
}

function waitForJobToFinish(jenkins, jobName, buildId, interval) {
  return waitForJobToFinishInner(jobName)
    .then((data) => {
      if ('SUCCESS' === data.result) {
        return data;
      }

      if (['ABORTED', 'FAILURE'].indexOf(data.result) > -1) {
        const errorMessage = `JENKINS[${ jobName }:${ buildId }] job ${ data.result }`;
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }

      return waitFor(interval)
        .then(() => waitForJobToFinish(jenkins, jobName, buildId, interval));
    });

  function waitForJobToFinishInner(jobName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jenkins.build.get(jobName, buildId, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
}

function waitFor(interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), interval));
}
```

Comment: Can't this be done by a simple javascript curl method rather than using npm?

Comment: @Jason you can do this totally vanilla with no additional libraries if that's the way you want to go. Basically, [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) is how you do an HTTP request in node, and [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) you can find what each Jenkins path is (you should use the equivalent to what I used in the answer). Sounds to me like a lot of extra work for not using some open source libraries that you can check their code for problems, no?